# Does C++ respond to javascript generated requests in node.js?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, mongodb

Just started learning [MongoDB](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/MongoDB/M101JS/2016_August/courseware) for node.js

In the third module video, **Overview of Building an App with MongoDB**, the speaker says:

> `node.js` is basically a `C++` program that you control using `V8 javascript`. So any applications you write using `node.js` will be written in `javascript` and it will control this `C++` application (`node.js`) and you'll be able to say something like they made request for this resource and your application actually in `javascript` will say: okey, they made a request for this resource, I don't have to respond to that. Now respond accordingly.

- Does it mean, `C++` is the one who responds to queries? But it's a language, not a server
- `Javascript` is not the one who runs on the `node`'s server?

Comment: c++ is a programming language not a server.

Comment: I understand that, so what does the speaker mean?

Comment: How could we know, we're not the _speaker_. ask them personally.

Comment: The node.js bindings are written in c++

Comment: @Drew So does it mean, javascript doesn't run on node.js's server?

Comment: Also V8 is in c++. Also means that since I am clueless, I just found this info on wikipedia :p

Comment: That is a really bad explanation I have ever came across about node.js or V8